# Need to Post json data using jQuery.ajax

Tags: json, jquery, post

I have a json of the following format which I need to send in the Ajax request through POST method:

```
  {
    “gbus”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “regions”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “offices”: [
        {
             "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “contracttypes”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “jobnumbers”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “disciplines”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Its not working for me, giving `500` error always when I try to submit it. Please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: can you show us your ajax function

Comment: Can you change give double inverted commas(") again? See “gbus”: should be "gbus"

Answer (score 0):

Can you change give double inverted commas(") again? See “gbus”: should be "gbus"

This is valid JSON

```
{
    "gbus": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    "regions": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    "offices": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    "contracttypes": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    "jobnumbers": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    "disciplines": [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
varJson =  {
    “gbus”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “regions”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “offices”: [
        {
             "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “contracttypes”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “jobnumbers”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ],
    “disciplines”: [
        {
            "code": "*"
        }
    ]
};

$.post("server.php", {'jsonPost[]': varJson}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

You need to configure your server in order to receive `$_POST('varJson')`